# Why does the type (or the scale) of rating statistics change?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-leagues

There is a little line showing users' ranking on the Reputation board that is at the Activity page (marked with red):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

---

Sometimes it shows the *year rank* while sometimes the *quarter* or *month ranks*. I wanted to know why the type (or the scale) of these statistics changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it varies, depending on one's length of time on the site; it also tends to reveal the most favorable statistic for any particular users.  Also I like your gravatar version of ViVid! ;D

Comment: Effective Jan 1, you may lose your this month's ranking, and see instead, this week's ranking, or the year ranking.  I believe the quarter ends Dec 31 as well.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your response! So you mean there is no strict rule for those changes, don't you? Also, I'm glad that you like the avatar :)

Comment: A related post on [meta.se]: [Why does the “top X%” in my profile change frequently between week/month/all time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92328)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statistic appears to be programmed to display the highest rank available between weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly and all-time (with a bias towards the longer-term in case of ties). You can check by clicking on the profiles of the leaders on the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/alltime/math/2010-07-20/).

Comment: I've looked through those ranks. While the statistic displays my monthly rank (#41), my highest rank seems to be weekly (#13)

Comment: VIVID: Likely because the number of users you are ranked among weekly is far smaller than the number of users you are ranked among in a monthly rank.  E.g., being 13th out of 200 is not as good as being ranked 41st out of 400.

Comment: @amWhy Oh really? I didn't know there were fewer people in Weekly league

Comment: Every user to have set foot in math.se prior to a week ago, and never since, are omitted.  This happens to be a "break" on math.se; fewer questions, less activity overall.    Recall, thousands of users preceded your registration on this site, and many of left, over time.  Participation varies among users.  Some are active sometimes, but not others, etc.  I wouldn't get too hung up on your rank, though.  It really means very little, in the whole scheme of things.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your detailed response! Now everything is clear! Definitely, there is no room for doubt that my ranking is just an invisible number in the community. The mere reason why I asked this question was my uncertainty of how it works. It's too early for me to get hung up with ranks while there are senior users like you! Thanks for making the MSE a better platform :)

Comment: Glad to help clarify.  Please note that I did not at all suggest your ranking now is of little significance.  It is!  It's good feedback that you are being very well received!  Keep up the good work!